# Working with Yandex Kassa

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, cryptography

It seems to me impossible to make a correct query to the service Yandex Kassa API. From the documentation (https://tech.yandex.ru/money/doc/payment-solution/payout/format-docpage/)

The problem is with the verification of the certificate. Error:

`SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed`

Has anyone some ideas? Maybe someone worked with it? Please share code.